# How to fetch specific data based on user's choice in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data

I'm working on a logic where the user is given a choice to mark the card categories he/she would like to study in the next study session, however, the current issue I'm facing is how am I going to fetch data based on the choice. The main point of the checkboxes is for user to press the category(or categories) that they would like to study in the `FlashCardSetView` after tapping the "Continue studying" button. For Example, a user might choose the 1 and 2 categories and the program would redirect to FlashcardSetView and the cards displayed would be the ones, the categories user previously chose. Additionally, to give more clarity, previously, each card is being assigned with a `cardStatus` (CoreData property) number that represents the category in which the card would go so that laterly, the user would be able to study cards he/she wants to.

**Here's the EndView (where user chooses what category of cards to study next):**

```
import SwiftUI
struct EndView: View {
var set: FlashSets
@ObservedObject var dataController = DataController.shared

@State private var continueFlashying = false
@State private var returnHome = false
@State private var selectedCategories: [CategorySelection] = [
    CategorySelection(category: 1, isSelected: false),
    CategorySelection(category: 2, isSelected: false),
    CategorySelection(category: 3, isSelected: false),
    CategorySelection(category: 4, isSelected: false)
]
var selectedCardStatuses: [Int] {
    return selectedCategories.filter { $0.isSelected }.map { $0.category }
}
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        VStack {
            Text("Set finished")
                .bold()
                .font(.system(size: 36))
                .padding()
            
            // Display the number of cards in each category
            List {
                ForEach(1...4, id: \.self) { category in
                    CategoryRow(categoryName: "Category \(category) cards studied: \(set.cardsArray.filter { $0.cardStatus == category }.count)", category: category, isSelected: $selectedCategories[category - 1].isSelected)
                }
            }
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    continueFlashying = true
                }) {
                    Text("Continue studying")
                    NavigationLink(destination: FlashcardSetView(set: set, selectedCardStatuses: selectedCardStatuses), isActive: $continueFlashying) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                }
                Button(action: {
                    // Handle the "Start again" button
                }) {
                    Text("Start again")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    returnHome = true
                }) {
                    // Return home button
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
}}

struct CategoryRow: View {
let categoryName: String
let category: Int
@Binding var isSelected: Bool

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text(categoryName)
        
        Spacer()
        
        CheckboxView(isSelected: $isSelected)
    }
}}
struct CheckboxView: View {
@Binding var isSelected: Bool

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        isSelected.toggle()
    }) {
        Image(systemName: isSelected ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
            .foregroundColor(isSelected ? .green : .secondary)
    }
}}
struct CategorySelection {
var category: Int
var isSelected: Bool
```

}

**Here's FlashcardSetView:**

```
struct FlashcardSetView: View {
//    @FetchRequest(entity: FlashSets.entity(),
//                  sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \FlashSets.date, ascending: false)])
@FetchRequest(
    entity: FlashCardData.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \FlashCardData.date, ascending: false)],
    predicate: NSPredicate(format: "cardStatus == %d", 3) // Fetch cards with category 3
)
var categoryThreeCards: FetchedResults<FlashCardData>

var set: FlashSets
@ObservedObject var dataController = DataController.shared
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@State private var showTermDefinitionView = false
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
@State private var isTapped = false
@State private var isEdited = false
//@State private var selectedCards: [FlashCardData] = [] // Keep track of selected cards
@State var allSwiped = false
@State private var showEndView = false
@State private var offset = CGSize.zero
@State private var currentlySelectedCard: FlashCardData?
@State var isLearned = false //1
@State var isThink = false  //2
@State var isHard = false   // 3
@State var isRepeat = false // 4
@State var studyPhase: StudyPhase = .initial
@State var currentCardIndex = 0
@State private var toEndView = false
var selectedCardStatuses: [Int]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: EndView(set: set), isActive: $toEndView) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            .isDetailLink(false)
            Text("Card list is empty‍♂️")
                .padding(.top, -50)
            if studyPhase == .initial {
                ForEach(set.cardsArray, id: \.self) { card in
                    //                    if let unwrappedCard = card {
                    //                        //Text(unwrappedCard.name)
                    //                    }
                    VStack {
                        Text("Cards studied: \(currentCardIndex)")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .offset(y: -20)
                        SingleFlashCard(cards: set.cardsArray,
                                        removal: {
                            withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                                removeCurrentCard()
                            }
                            print("Removing card with animation")
                        }, set: set, currentCardIndex: $currentCardIndex, isLearned: $isLearned,
                                        isThink: $isThink,
                                        isHard: $isHard,
                                        isRepeat: $isRepeat)
                        .offset(y: -20)
                        .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .opacity, removal: .opacity))
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        currentlySelectedCard = card
                        // Automatically transition to the EndView when all cards are studied
                    }
                }
            }
            if studyPhase == .hard {
                ForEach(categoryThreeCards, id: \.self) { card in
                    //                    if let unwrappedCard = card {
                    //                        //Text(unwrappedCard.name)
                    //                    }
                    VStack {
                        Text(set.cardsArray.count.description)
                        SingleFlashCard(cards: set.cardsArray,
                                        removal: {
                            withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                                removeCurrentCard()
                            }
                            print("Removing card with animation")
                        }, set: set, currentCardIndex: $currentCardIndex, isLearned: $isLearned,
                                        isThink: $isThink,
                                        isHard: $isHard,
                                        isRepeat: $isRepeat)
                        .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .opacity, removal: .opacity))
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        currentlySelectedCard = card
                    }
                }
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: EditFlashCardView(dataController: dataController, set: set), isActive: $isEdited) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
        }
    }
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                            Menu("Options") {
        Button(action: {
            showTermDefinitionView = true
        }) {
            NavigationLink(destination: TermDefinitionView(currentSet: set), isActive: $showTermDefinitionView) {
                Text("Add cards")
            }
        }
        Button(action: {
            isEdited = true
        }) {
            Text("Edit cards")
        }
    }
    )
    
    HStack {
        Button(action: {
            currentlySelectedCard?.cardStatus = 1
            
            //removeCard(currentlySelectedCard)
            self.isLearned.toggle()
            removeCurrentCard()
        }) {
            Text("")
                .frame(width: 70, height: 50)
                .background(Color("Easy"))
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
        }
        
        .padding(.trailing, 20)
        
        Button(action: {
            // Handle button action
            self.isThink.toggle()
            currentlySelectedCard?.cardStatus = 2
            removeCurrentCard()
        }) {
            Text("")
                .frame(width: 70, height: 50)
                .background(Color("Think"))
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
        }
        .padding(.trailing, 20)
        
        Button(action: {
            // Handle button action
            self.isHard.toggle()
            currentlySelectedCard?.cardStatus = 3
            removeCurrentCard()
        }) {
            Text("")
                .frame(width: 70, height: 50)
                .background(Color("Hard"))
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
        }
        .padding(.trailing, 20)
        Button(action: {
            // Handle button action
            self.isRepeat.toggle()
            currentlySelectedCard?.cardStatus = 4
            removeCurrentCard()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "repeat.circle.fill")
                .frame(width: 70, height: 50)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.red)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
        }
    }
}
private func removeCurrentCard() {
    if studyPhase == .initial {
        if currentCardIndex < set.cardsArray.count - 1 {
            currentCardIndex += 1 // Move to the next card
            currentlySelectedCard = set.cardsArray[currentCardIndex] // Update currentlySelectedCard
        } else {
            if let lastCard = set.cardsArray.last {
                // All cards in the set have been studied
                toEndView = true // Transition to the EndView
            } else {
                studyPhase = .hard // Transition to the "hard" study phase if there are more cards
            }
        }
    } else if studyPhase == .hard {
        if currentCardIndex < categoryThreeCards.count - 1 {
            currentCardIndex += 1 // Move to the next card
            currentlySelectedCard = categoryThreeCards[currentCardIndex] // Update currentlySelectedCard
        } else {
            if categoryThreeCards.isEmpty {
                // All "hard" cards are studied
                toEndView = true // Transition to the EndView
            } else {
                // Handle the case when there are more cards in category 3
            }
        }
    }
}


//    func removeMethod(at index: Int) {
//        set.cardsArray.remove(at: index)
//    }
```

}

**SingleFlashCard:**

```
struct SingleFlashCard: View {
let cards: [FlashCardData]
var removal: (() -> Void)? = nil
var set: FlashSets
@State private var isTapped = false
@Binding var currentCardIndex: Int
@Binding var isLearned: Bool
@Binding var isThink: Bool
@Binding var isHard: Bool
@Binding var isRepeat: Bool

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
            .fill(Color.white)
        //.offset(x: isLearned ? 500 : 0)
        //.overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25).stroke(getColor(), lineWidth: 2))// Here we change the border color based on the swipe direction
            .shadow(radius: 3)
        
        VStack {
            NavigationStack {
                Text(currentCardIndex < set.cardsArray.count ? (set.cardsArray[currentCardIndex].term ?? "Unnamed Card") : "No more cards")

                    .offset(y: -100)
                Divider()
                
                if isTapped {
                    Text(currentCardIndex < set.cardsArray.count ? (set.cardsArray[currentCardIndex].definition ?? "Unnamed Card") : "No more cards")
                        .offset(y: 100)
                }
            }
            
            
        }
        
        
    }
    .frame(width: 300, height: 500)
}
```

}

**DataController file to control the CoreData:**

```
class DataController:  ObservableObject {
static let shared = DataController()
@Published var termdefpairs: [TermAndDefinition] =
```

[TermAndDefinition(term: "", definition: "")]
@Published var savedFlash: [FlashCardData] = []

```
@Published var dataUpdated: Bool = false


let container: NSPersistentContainer

init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
    container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreData")
    
    if inMemory {
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
    }
    // super.init()
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
        self.container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
    })
    
    container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    //fetchRequest()
}
func addNew() {
    termdefpairs.append(TermAndDefinition(term: "", definition: ""))
}
func fetchRequest() {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<FlashCardData> = FlashCardData.fetchRequest()
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \FlashCardData.date, ascending: false)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    
    do {
        self.savedFlash = try container.viewContext.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to fetch FlashCardData: \(error)")
    }
}


func save() {
    do {
        try container.viewContext.save()
        print("Data saved")
        self.dataUpdated.toggle()  // This will trigger the view to update
    } catch {
        print("We could not save the data...")
    }
}

func add(term: String, definition: String, number: Int16, date: Date) {
    let data = FlashCardData(context: self.container.viewContext)
    data.id = UUID()
    data.definition = definition
    data.term = term
    data.number = number
    //   data.tag = tag
    data.date = date
    //      data.name = name
    // fetchRequest()
}

func addFlashcardSet(name: String, tag: String, date: Date)  {
    let newSet = FlashSets(context: self.container.viewContext)
    newSet.id = UUID()
    newSet.name = name
    newSet.tag = tag
    newSet.date = Date()
}
func update(data: FlashCardData, term: String, defintion: String, date: Date, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    data.term = term
    data.definition = defintion
    data.date = Date()
    save()
}
func deleteFlashCard(data: FlashCardData) {
    container.viewContext.delete(data)
    save()
}
func updateFlashSet(set: FlashSets, name: String, tag: String, date: Date) {
    set.name = name
    set.tag = tag
    set.date = date
    save()
}
```

}

[image: FlashCardData entity]

[image: FlashSets entity]

Comment: Please try to make this question a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that it's easier to understand.

Comment: thank you for your response, I added additional code that might help you with controlling the CoreData